# Where is the Eclipse Wild Web Developer YAML editor?

Tags: eclipse, yaml, editor, wildwebdeveloper

I had WWD installed from Eclipse Marketplace but when I tried `.yml` or `.yaml` → *Open With* → *Other...* there was no *YAML Editor* to choose:

[image]

I de- and re-installed WWD. To no avail.

---

Additional question:

Do I remember correctly that the need for an Eclipse restart after SW installation wasn't necessary somewhen in the past? (That's how OSGi's `bundle:install` is supposed to work anyway, isn't it?) All of the recent installations I performed (in v2022-12) needed a restart.

**UPDATE** (answers add'l question)

See [John Arthorne's](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/73762/john-arthorne) [answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/177361/153444) to [*Why does Eclipse need to be restarted after installing a plugin?*](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/168317/153444) (And–Hooray!–I remembered correctly. No need to retire soon.)

> The Eclipse platform does support dynamically installing plugins without restarting. In the past this option was made available via an "Apply Now" option. Unfortunately for this to work properly the plugin itself also needs to support dynamic behavior. The large majority of Eclipse plugins out there are not dynamic themselves - they don't clean up after themselves, and they don't dynamically react to services or extensions being added/removed after they have started. [...]

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse Wild Web Developer supports different languages and formats via the ***Generic Text Editor***.

> [To see it in action, open the desired file with the Generic Editor
> that's included by default in the Eclipse IDE.](https://github.com/eclipse/wildwebdeveloper#eclipse-wild-web-developer---web-dev-in-eclipse-ide-)

To your additional question:
This has always depended on which extension points are used (whether the extensions are read at startup, lazy at first use or dynamically) and on the implementation of the plugins using these extension points, OSGi declarative services or other non-declarative, but programmatic ways of extension. If you deny *Restart Now*, then not everything might be available. In other words, *Apply Now* happens implicitly and you can choose *Restart Now* in addition. Quite some time ago a flag was considered for the plugin to install to suppress the *Restart Now* prompt. But the user experience of such a wrongly set flag would be much worse than a few unnecessary *Restart Now* prompts. To be sure that it works, you would have to test the whole functionality after installations in all combinations of plugins in different versions being present before installation and which might have been installed before with or without restart.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I think re-using **Generic Text Editor** isn't the best choice. If I open a YAML file that hasn't a `.yml` or `.yaml` extension it isn't recognized as such by GTE and, for instance, no syntax coloring is applied. An example are Salt config files with the extension `.sls`: [states file `top.sls`](https://docs.saltproject.io/salt/user-guide/en/latest/topics/states.html#the-top-sls-file), [pillar SLS files](https://docs.saltproject.io/salt/user-guide/en/latest/topics/pillar.html#basics). For these I have to stick to _Yaml Editor_ or _Liclipse Yaml Editor_.

Comment: You can configure this in the preferences _General > Content Types_: to the content type _Text > Wild Web Developer supported web dev file > YAML_ add the _File association_ `*.sls`. If you think this is a good idea in general, not just for yourself, make a [pull request to change it here](https://github.com/eclipse/wildwebdeveloper/blob/93a1e6d07ab7cb64ef11f318ad0a981095565d28/org.eclipse.wildwebdeveloper/plugin.xml#L733).